# setInterval is not stopping in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom

I want to make an automatic Image slider. And, when user hove over the image slider the auto slider will stop work and when leave the slide, then auto slide will start again.

```html
 <div class="slider-wrapper">
        <ul class="slider">
            <li>
                <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2022/07/31/20/32/vintage-bus-7356817_960_720.jpg" alt="">
            </li>
            <li>
                <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2022/04/20/00/09/flowers-7143991_960_720.jpg" alt="">
            </li>
            <li>
                <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2022/03/26/15/17/cornelian-cherry-7093063_960_720.jpg" alt="">
            </li>
            <li>
                <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2013/08/20/15/47/poppies-174276_960_720.jpg" alt="">
            </li>
            <li>
                <img class="image" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2022/07/25/16/41/child-7344169_960_720.jpg"
                    alt="">
            </li>
            <li>
                <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2021/08/08/22/41/flowers-6532105_960_720.jpg" alt="">
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

```js
const slider = document.querySelector(".slider");
const sliderWrapper = document.querySelector(".slider-wrapper");

let currentSlide = 0;

function nextSlide(slide) {
  Array.from(slider.children).forEach((item, index) => {
    item.style.transform = `translateX(${100 * (index - slide)}%)`;
  });
}

nextSlide(0); // initial slide on mounted

var stopSliding = null;

function startAutoSliding() {
  stopSliding = setInterval(() => {
    console.log("Next Clicked");
    currentSlide++;
    if (currentSlide >= 0 && currentSlide < slideLength) {
      nextSlide(currentSlide);
    } else {
      currentSlide = 0;
      nextSlide(currentSlide);
    }
    console.log(currentSlide);
  }, 4000);
}

sliderWrapper.addEventListener("mouseover", (event) => {
  console.log("mouseover");
  event.stopPropagation();
  clearInterval(stopSliding);
});

sliderWrapper.addEventListener("mouseleave", (event) => {
  event.stopPropagation();
  console.log("mouseleave");
  startAutoSliding();
  stopSliding = null;
});
startAutoSliding();
```

But, when I am hovering its stop for the first time, but when again hovering its not stopping.

StackBlitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-gqgyjj?file=index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you reassign `stopSliding` to null after you start sliding again. just removed `stopSliding = null;` from `mouseleave` event.

Answer (score 2):

The reason this happen because when you `mouseleave`, you invoke `startAutoSliding()` but after that you assign `stopSliding = null;`
Which makes it unclearable, what the code basically does is:
`clearInterval(null)`

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, you need to remove `stopSliding = null` from your `mouseleave` event.

This happens because when you create an interval it will return to you a random ID. You have to know that ID to pass it into clearInterval for it to actually stop that interval. When you reassign your pointer (`stopSliding` variable) to something else (like `null`) before you pass it into clearInterval then you don't know the id anymore. So when you call clearInterval you're passing `null` and now it doesn't know the id of interval to clear so it does nothing.